# GTA 5 save help

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

My GTA 5 game won't save! I've done the mission where you have to save Jimmy from the stolen boat, and farther into the game. I beat a mission where I had to take photos of a jewelry store's air ducts. I saved after that mission, loaded the game a few days later and have to save Jimmy from the boat again! HELP!

Comment: Try going to your device settings. Go to your save game, press yellow button on GTA5 and delete system updates. If there's any ! anywhere, delete them. Also see how much space you have. Can you quicksave on the phone? If you can't exit, get a usb or memory card.

Comment: You might have saved in a different slot but are still loading the old save. Have you tried loading a different save?

Answer (score -3):

Make sure auto save is always on before and after a mission, if that doesn't work then I don't know.